# MonoTouch UITableView with images

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I have to create a `UITableView` with an image on the left, a title on the center, and a subtitle (smaller) on the right

At this moment, I have this code in the `GetCell` of the `TableViewDataSource`:

```
UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (kCellIdentifier);
if (cell == null)
{
     cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default,kCellIdentifier);
     //var img = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromFile ("Images/altalenaBox.png"));
     //cell.BackgroundView = img;
}
cell.TextLabel.Text = list[indexPath.Row];
return cell;
```

How to create multiple columns in this cell??

Answer (score 0):

For creating custom cells I use the XIB editor - following this tutorial http://www.alexyork.net/blog/2011/07/18/creating-custom-uitableviewcells-with-monotouch-the-correct-way/

This tutorial has worked for me several times :) Although I have also hit some problems where the XIBs just won't work (it's a learning work in progress for me!)

Answer (score 0):

You should sub-class `UITableViewCell` and layout your own cell. Add an image and 2 labels then position them correcly using x,y coordinates.

Then in `GetCell()`, create an instance of your cell containing the correct data.

Comment: many thanks. how to add images and labels to the cell by code?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `UITableView` API is not easy nor very .NET friendly.

If you have not already then I suggest you to have a good look at [MonoTouch.Dialog](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog) which is now (since version 5.2) shipped with MonoTouch.

It will allow you to do almost everything you can do with an `UITableView` but with an API that is much easier to learn (and more .NET-y). You can find a Sample application (on github) that shows most of it's features.

Also a lot of questions (and answers) can be found about it here on stackoverflow.com and many people will be able to help you using it.